Next.js request.nextUrl.pathname return always /
In nextjs , I am trying to get current url path in middleware by using request.nextUrl.pathname. Currently request.nextUrl.pathname always return '/' for any route. For example  when I try with http://localhost:3000/dashboard, request.nextUrl.pathname returns '/' but I expect /dashboard. What do I miss ?
Note: I use nextjs 14 with app router
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export async function  middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  
    const session = await getSession({});

    if(session != null){
        console.log("sdsdsdsdsds")
        return NextResponse.next()
    }else{

        if(request.nextUrl.pathname ='/'){
            console.log("current pathname is "+request.nextUrl.pathname)
            return NextResponse.next()
        }

        const signPageUrl = request.nextUrl.origin+"/api/auth/signin"
        console.log('no session for '+ request.nextUrl.pathname)
        return NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl.origin)
    }
  

